# JSF unable to modify facet

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am trying to modify a facet in my .xhtml file programatically. I am using Primefaces 6.1.

I have the following code in .xhtml

```
<p:menubar model="#{menu.model}" id="myMenu">
    <f:facet name="options">

    </f:facet>
</p:menubar>
```

In my bean I have the following code to update "options" facet.

```
@PostConstruct
public void initMenu(){     
// getting data is skipped
    HtmlPanelGrid mainPanel = new HtmlPanelGrid();
    HtmlOutputLabel htmlOutputLabel = new HtmlOutputLabel();
    htmlOutputLabel.setValue("Search Template");
    mainPanel.getFacets().put("options",htmlOutputLabel);    
}
```

mainPanel.getFacets() returns no facets hence can't add the label.

How can I programmatically access and modify the facet? I am stumped.

Comment: Why should a newly (in a wrong way btw) created **panelgrid** return the facets of a non-related menubar???

Answer (score 0):

In order to `getFacets()` from `menubar` you need to get reference on instance of existing `menubar`.

You can achieve this by binding `p:menubar` to server side component instance.

1. In you managed bean add

`private org.primefaces.component.menubar.Menubar menubar;`

and add getter and setter.

2. Add `binding` attribute to `p:menubar` like this

   ```
   <p:menubar model="#{menu.model}" id="myMenu" binding="#{menu.menubar}">
       <f:facet name="options">

       </f:facet>
   </p:menubar>
   ```
3. Inside @PostConstruct method add

   ```
   @PostConstruct
   public void initMenu() {
       // getting data is skipped
       //initMenuModel();

       menubar=(Menubar)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createComponent(Menubar.COMPONENT_TYPE);
       HtmlOutputText htmlOutputLabel = new HtmlOutputText();
       htmlOutputLabel.setValue("Search Template");
       Map<String, UIComponent> facets = menubar.getFacets();
       facets.put("options", htmlOutputLabel);
   }
   ```

Also check recommendations and best practices regarding [JSF 'binding' attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used).

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer. Sure thus works with the declaratively added menumodel? And it is not good practice to create components via 'new'.

Comment: I've tested this solution with a case that user posted (no declarative data model). I agree its not best practice but I think there is no harm in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the reference to the menuModel was declared via an attribute, not a declarative menu structure. OP has that in his question.

Comment: @Kukeltje, ok. Now I understand what you meant. Anyways, I've tested solution and it works as expected.

Comment: Still, doing 'new MenuBar()' is not good practice... You should use the `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()` and create the component this way

Comment: @Kukeltje, thank you for pointing that. I've updated my answer and also added additional resource for learning.